# Initialize pointer inside structure efficiently in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization, structure

How will I initialize the following data structure efficiently(without spending any compute) ? It consists of an array of  `struct Register` . The length of array which FieldArrayPointer of each  `struct Register`  is pointing will be different.How will I extract pointer (Using a compiler directive ?) and use it to initialize  `struct Register` array ? Is there any alternate way to create a data structure like this (I don't want to use linked list)?
(N can be arbitrarily large)

```
    struct Field
    {
        char    High;                
        char    Low;                
        char    Attribute;
    } FieldArray[L0+L1+L2...+L(N-1)];

    struct Register 
    {
       unsigned int    ResetValue;
       unsigned int    FieldArrayLength;
       struct Field    *FieldArrayPointer;
    } RegisterArray[N] =

    { ResetValue0,     L0,    <Pointer of FieldArray[0].Field>,
      ResetValue1,     L1,    <Pointer of FieldArray[L0].Field>,
      ResetValue2,     L2,    <Pointer of FieldArray[L0+L1].Field>,
      . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ,
      ResetValue(N-1), L(N-1),<Pointer of FieldArray[L0+L1+..+L(N-2)].Field>
    };

   //L0,L1,L2.. and N are constant integers
```

Comment: What's wrong with using a for loop? An initialiser will generate code anyway, so there's no solution that doesn't 'spend compute.'

Comment: There could be if I know where compiler is going to put FieldArray in memory. {ResetValue0,L0,0x12345678,}

Comment: Have you tried timing a hand-coded version for, say N=1000, and seeing how it compares to using a for loop to see if it gives you any speedup? Any solution (eg code generation) is going to be ugly and it would be a pity to do it if there's no benefit.

Comment: I am generating this code with Perl for large number of Registers and if I can get a compiler directive to extract the address of each of field array elements, that would work perfectly for me.

Comment: A rather basic question: You are concerned that the compiler will generate code to compute L0+L1+L2 and so on? Are these values constant? Also: What do you mean by 'extract the address'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that `FieldArray` has static storage duration and `L0` through `Ln` are integer constant expressions, you can simply do:

```
struct Register 
 {
    unsigned int    ResetValue;
    unsigned int    FieldArrayLength;
    struct Field    *FieldArrayPointer;
 } RegisterArray[N] =
 { 
   { ResetValue0,     L0,    FieldArray + 0 },
   { ResetValue1,     L1,    FieldArray + L0 },
   { ResetValue2,     L2,    FieldArray + L0 + L1 },
   ...
 };
```

If writing that out by hand is too cumbersome, you could write a code generator to create the source and `#include` the result.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are concerned that the calculation of L0+L1+L2 etc takes time.

If L0, L1 and so on are constants, and like you mention, a perl script generates code with these values, *any* decent optimizing compiler will precalculate these values.

It's called Constant Propagation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding

gcc can do it, for example:

Here is a piece of code I wrote:

```
char fubar[100];

struct bar
{
  char *ptr;
  int length;
} array[3] =
{
  {fubar, 10},
  {fubar+10, 20},
  {fubar+10+20, 70}
};
```

Here is what 'gcc -O2' generated:

```
.globl array
    .data
    .align 4
    .type   array, @object
    .size   array, 24
array:
    .long   fubar
    .long   10
    .long   fubar+10
    .long   20
    .long   fubar+30
    .long   70
    .comm   fubar,100,32
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
    .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The generated code does *not* calculate the offsets each time.